# Subscript out of range when referencing to cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that has a range of value (eg. 100 - 1000). I want to copy the upper bound and lower bound to two different columns. Here's the code:
`

```
Sub ProcessData()
Dim col As String
Dim ltarget As String
Dim htarget As String
Dim SheetC As Integer
Dim SL As Integer
SL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For SheetC = 2 To SL
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetC).Activate
    'deleteempty ("D")
    addzeroes ("D")
    insertcol ("E:F")
    Range("E1").Value = "LSV"
    Range("F1").Value = "HSV"
    getvalues "D", "E", "F"
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.autofit
Next SheetC
End Sub
Function deleteempty(col)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, col).Value = "" Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Function
Function addzeroes(col)
    Dim temp As String
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 2 To Rows.Count
        temp = Cells(j, col).Value
        temp = Replace(temp, "K", "000")
        temp = Replace(temp, "M", "000000")
        Cells(j, col).Value = temp
    Next j
End Function
Function insertcol(col)
    Range(col).EntireColumn.Insert
End Function
Function getvalues(col, ltarget, htarget)
    Dim temp As String
    ReDim strs(1 To 2) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        temp = Cells(i, col).Value
        strs = Split(temp, "–")
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ltarget).Value = strs(1)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, htarget).Value = strs(2)
        'Cells(i, ltarget).Value = CInt(Cells(i, ltarget).Value)
        'Cells(i, htarget).Value = CInt(Cells(i, htarget).Value)
    Next i
End Function`
```

I'm getting the "subscript out of range" error at

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, htarget).Value = strs(2)
```

Any thoughts on what is going on? Thanks. 
PS: Focus on the getvalues function

Comment: For some reason it's not starting the array at 1, but 0.  Use `strs(0)` and `strs(1)`. You don't have a `strs(2)`.

Comment: It doesnt look like you have strs dim'd. I see you redim it but confused as to why that isnt erroring out>

Comment: @DougCoats it may be global?

Comment: @EganWolf then that just means he didnt give us all the details we need :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code need that Function change to  sub and specifying the Worksheet.

```
Sub ProcessData()
Dim col As String
Dim ltarget As String
Dim htarget As String
Dim SheetC As Integer
Dim SL As Integer
SL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For SheetC = 2 To SL
    DeleteEmpty "D", Sheets(SheetC)
    With Sheets(SheetC)
        addzeroes "D", Sheets(SheetC)
        insertcol "E:F", Sheets(SheetC)
        .Range("E1").Value = "LSV"
        .Range("F1").Value = "HSV"
        getvalues "D", Sheets(SheetC)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
Next SheetC
End Sub
Sub DeleteEmpty(col As String, Ws As Worksheet)
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range, rngU As Range
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range(.Range(col & 2), .Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End If
    For Each rng In rngDB
        If rng = "" Then
            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU = rng
            Else
                Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
Sub addzeroes(col, Ws As Worksheet)
    Dim temp As String
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range, rngU As Range
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range(.Range(col & 2), .Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End If
    For Each rng In rngDB
        temp = rng.Value
        temp = Replace(temp, "K", "000")
        temp = Replace(temp, "M", "000000")
        rng = temp
    Next rng
End Sub
Sub insertcol(col, Ws As Worksheet)
    Ws.Range(col).EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
Sub getvalues(col As String, Ws As Worksheet)

    Dim temp As String
    Dim Strs As Variant
    Dim i As Long, rngDB As Range, rng As Range, rngU As Range
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range(.Range(col & 2), .Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End If
    For Each rng In rngDB
        temp = rng.Value
        Strs = Split(temp, "?")
        rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Strs
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, good sir. This worked out smooth. I think I was getting the error because I was using functions instead of subs. I'm new to VBA, so I don't know. But I'd be grateful if you briefly explain where I was going wrong. Again thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

From the [help for the Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/split-function):

> Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array

The array returned by `Split` has to be assigned to a dynamic array - otherwise you get a "Can't assign to array" error. A dynamic array is just an array that was declared without explicitly specified dimensions - e.g. `Dim a() As String`

`Split` doesn't look at any existing array bounds and isn't affected by an `Option Base 1` statement. The lower bound of the array returned by `Split` will always be zero and the upper bound will be one less than the number of substrings found

Comment: You just need to adjust the subscripts to reflect the fact that the array is zero-based (as mentioned in a comment by @BruceWayne), so: `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ltarget).Value = strs(0)` and `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, htarget).Value = strs(1)`